# mPDF error: IMAGE Error (...) Could not find image file

Tags: html, image, pdf-generation, codeigniter-3, mpdf

Baiscally I make a *pdf file out of html view file* (**mpdf** library), the latter containing image. Image is not displayed. When I insert `$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;` I get the error and the (image exists and accessible). I don’t know why this is happening, and I heed help.

I've tried with absolute path and https:// - nothing works.
This is the error message I get from the cron:

> **mPDF error:** IMAGE Error
>   (https://mysite.lv/assets/design/image.png): Could not find image file

or

> **mPDF error:** IMAGE Error
>   (var/www/html/bank/assets/design/image.png): Could not find image file

Comment: Did you find answer? I have same issue

Comment: @Kref, I've found the solution, yet the code pertains to my former employer. Can't remember details. Seems to me, I've broken thru using `.jpg` image.

Answer (score 1):

My problem when i got this error was I hadn't enabled open_ssl in my php.ini file.  I removed the ; in front of extension=php_openssl.dll, restarted my web server and it started working.